# Monitor file change - Asyncio and Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, python-asyncio

I have a flask dev server and want to include a file monitoring feature that sends the client a notification when a monitored file has changed. This is similar to flask's auto_reload feature, but i'm not trying to reload the server, simply (and using Flask-Socketio) send this notification.

I've looked at using asyncio (and py3.5) and [watchdog](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog) for this. Watchdog examples require a standalone script to run, which seems unnecessary since flask is already running. Lost in a soup of callbacks, run_in_executor (which for some reason blocks), etc.

Any pointers on how this feature can be elegantly achieved?

Answer (score -1):

Initialize and run the `watchdog` `observer` in a separate thread in your Flask app. In the callback that is received from `watchdog`, do a `socketio.emit()` to send a message back to your client.